# allow non logged in user to upload images in media library

Tags: user-roles, media-library, permissions

I have a website where I have a page that is accessible from any non logged in user . Its a form where I need to upload image through the form but when I try this its showing an error. But When I logeed in form works fine.

So I tried this code

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {    
   do_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );
} else {
   do_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );
}
```

But its not working. I need to know how to How to allow  non logged in user to upload images in media library?

Comment: edit your question to show us the code you try for the form

Answer (score 0):

The hook [wp_ajax_{action}](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) is for logged-in users and [`wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)) for non logged-in users.

For example in your functions.php file,

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_your_ajax_action', 'your_ajax_function_callback' ); // logged-in users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_your_ajax_action', 'your_ajax_function_callback' ); // logged-out users

function your_ajax_function_callback() {
    // handle ajax request
}
```

Comment: Would you please explain how i use it in function.php file?

Comment: @Amit I improved the code example as the previous wasn't quite right after all. You can add the `add_action()`s and the callback function to your functions.php file. Replace the `your_ajax_action` part of the hooks with the proper action name and fill in the callback function. The ajax documentation provides further details, https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Hello Sir, Can you please explain how I can give non login user to photo upload permission?

Comment: @Amit Are you having difficulties getting your existing code working or are you just starting to write the required code? If you have some code already, please edit your question to include relevant parts of your code so that the community can have a look at it.

Comment: Hi, Just trying to figure out how I can enable upload photo option for non logged in user? The form is working when i am login but not working when I logged out. Can you please help me?

Comment: @Amit Perhpas, but not without seeing some code first.